# How do I load different logback configuration for Maven/Surefire and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, logback, maven-surefire-plugin

I want to have different default logback configurations for my unit tests in Eclipse and Maven (surefire plugin).  Basically, I want any logs generated during tests to be sent to the console in Eclipse or to a file for Maven.

Currently, I have a single logback-test.xml that has both appenders.

I think the solution involves adding a different logback-test.xml for the two classpaths.  But how do I do that?  Having something manual in maven is likely ok (in a profile for example), but requiring a manual change to Eclipse (across lots of projects) would be extremely annoying.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can always override logback configuration file lookup using the system property `logback.configurationFile`.

For Maven, you can add the following to the configuration section of the `maven-surefire-plugin`:

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
    <logback.configurationFile>${basedir}/src/test/resources/logback-maven.xml</logback.configurationFile>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

Comment: Just want to add note that might be useful to one who had made all as said in accepted answer but still don't get logback configuration file in charge: Problem could be in dependency. If you have slf4j-api-simple-*.jar in classpath it will not use logback configuration file. Just remove it. Here is original: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34343478/1068013