# Logback is not using configuration file

Tags: java, logback

i'm trying to save the log of a process to a file. This works fine when I run the class in netbeans, but after I export the JAR file there is no way the process pick the logback.xml.

The jar file is in the same path than logback.xml. I've tried using all the examples i've found here:

Using the command line file:

```
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml test.jar
```

Setting the classpath:

```
java =cp "./" -jar test.jar
```

This is the configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <!--<Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} %M:%L- %msg%n</Pattern> -->
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} %M:%L - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
            <!--<Pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %C{0}:%L - 
                %msg%n</Pattern> -->
        </encoder>
    </appender>



    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>test.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>test.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <!--<pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern> -->
            <pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %C{0}:%L -
                %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Please help! Thanks

Comment: Why is the config file not inside the jar?

Comment: I dont't know. Should be there? Anyway.. I've tried adding  the xml in the JAR file but it keeps using the default configuration,

Comment: You seem to be missing the `<configuration>` tags from the configuration, or did you leave them out?

Comment: My mistake doing copy/paste. But like I said, this works on Netbeans. But if I use the jar, for example, eclipse, always use the default configuration. Doesn't matter where the file is.

Comment: Well, it looks for `logback.xml` in the classpath. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: arrgg.. I found the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem:

I had logback.*.jar and slf4j-api-simple-1.7.12.jar in my classpath. So It was using simple instead of logback.

I deleted simple, now works perfect.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also turns out I had a dependency (transitive, maven) on "slf4j-simple" and that was being preferred "in favor of the built in default: logback" even though logback was also present. Not easily figure-out-able...also look for any other extraneous slf4j bindings, like log4j...

Also note you may need to do a maven `mvn dependency:tree` to find all the dependencies, since effective-pom only shows "compile" time dependencies, not runtime (the latter being also included in shaded jars...).

Fix in my particular case was to exclude slf4j-simple from the dependency itself (postgresql jdbc in this case).