# How to define a variable in Logback with a default value and override it?

Tags: java, maven, logback, maven-surefire-plugin

I would like to define a property/variable in Logback (1.2.1) that:

- Has a default value
- Can be overriden via a Java command-line option

Basically, during development, I would like Maven to be invoking the `maven-surefire-plugin` with something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <log.dir>${project.build.directory}/logs</log.dir>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

(I am sure that the above is working fine, because I have other properties being passed in for the tests this way and those work as expected).

At the moment, I have the following `logback.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds" debug="false">

    <property name="log.dir" value="."/>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${log.dir}/logs/my.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>strongbox_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>

            <fileNamePattern>strongbox-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>128MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>31</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>

            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS dd-MM-yyyy} | %-5.5p | %-20.20t | %-50.50logger{50} | %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    ...
</configuration>
```

The `-Dlog.dir=foo/logs`, it is simply being ignored and the log file is being produced in the current directory. What am I doing wrong here? Does it need a scope? Does it need an `if` condition to be set up?

Comment: Please wrap your path argument with doule quote ("). It should looks like -Dlog.dir="foo/logs"

Comment: @eg04lt3r, Thanks, but this is not the problem.

Comment: I think that you can only override logback file with right property. Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32658635/how-do-i-load-different-logback-configuration-for-maven-surefire-and-eclipse.

Comment: This involves having a different `logback.xml` file per environment, which is also not what I'd like to do. From what I understand, Logback supports `properties`, which can be used inside the `logback.xml` file. I would like to be able to have a default value defined for a property inside the `logback.xml` for the cases where this is not being overriden from the console via `-Dproperty1=....`.

Answer (score 16):

If you need a variable, say called `log.file.root`, which should default to a value `app-logs`, define it as:

`<property name="LOG_ROOT" value="${log.file.root:-app-logs}" />`

Then use `${LOG_ROOT}` wherever you need to.

This variable can be overridden via the command line by:

```
-Dlog.file.root=/home/user/logs
```

Reference: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html -> "Default values for variables"

Answer (score 2):

You specify the property for the maven-surefire-plugin.
So the property will be bound only for this plugin execution :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <log.dir>${project.build.directory}/logs</log.dir>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In your case, you want that the property be bound whatever the executed plugin.
Not only for test executions.

So you should use properties declared in the  `<build>` tag of the pom.

```
<build>
      ...
  <properties>
     <log.dir>${project.build.directory}/logs</log.dir>
  </properties>
      ...
</build>
```

In order that the Maven property used in the logback configuration be replaced by the actual value computed from the pom, you have to enable the Maven resources filtering :

```
  ...
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
  ...
```

And the Logback configuration has to be located inside the `src/main/resources` folder of course (this folder or a child).

Comment: Thanks, but what you're talking about is Maven resource filtering and I'm not looking to do resource filtering.

Comment: You are welcome but the way where you want to use to value your property placeholder :         `<file>${log.dir}/logs/my.log</file>` looks like file filtering feature.

Comment: It's documented in the Logback docs for properties/variables and it's a better solution than Maven filtering as the values is not replaced in the actual resources file (which is what will happen with the Maven filtering).